# Create Split order without plugin woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, split

```php
<?php 
// Register custom endpoint for split orders
function custom_endpoint_for_split_orders() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'split-orders', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
   // flush_rewrite_rules(); // Flush rewrite rules to ensure the new endpoint is recognized
`your text`}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_endpoint_for_split_orders' );


function custom_endpoint_for_split_orderss() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'split-order', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_endpoint_for_split_orderss' );

function flush_rewrite_rules_on_activation() {
    custom_endpoint_for_split_orders(); // Register the endpoint
    custom_endpoint_for_split_orderss();
    flush_rewrite_rules(); // Flush rewrite rules
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules_on_activation' );

// Add menu item for split orders in "My Account" navigation
function add_split_orders_menu_item( $items ) {
    
    $items['split-orders'] = 'Orders 2';
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_split_orders_menu_item' );


function add_split_orders_table_menu_item( $items ) {
    $new_items`your text` = array();

    // Copy existing menu items
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        $new_items[ $key ] = $item;

        // Insert the new menu item before the 'dashboard' item
        if ( $key === 'orders' ) {
            $new_items['split-orders'] = 'Orders 2';
        }
    }

    return $new_items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_split_orders_table_menu_item' );


/////// Mneu  code end  Here   
//adding splitting order functionality show  in  wp-admin Order table 
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {   
    // Array to store split orders
    $split_orders = array();

    // Get all items in the order
    $order_items = $order->get_items();

    // Flags to check if any product from category 494 and other categories is found
    $products_in_category_494 = false;
    $products_in_other_categories = false;

    // Create new split order only if there are products from both category 494 and other categories
    $split_order_needed = false;

    // Iterate through order items
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
        // Get the WC_Product Object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Get categories of the product
        $product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();

        // Check if the product belongs to the specified category (category ID: 494)
        if (in_array('494', $product_categories)) {
            // Set flag to true
            $products_in_category_494 = true;
        } else {
            // Set flag for other categories
            $products_in_other_categories = true;
        }
    }

    // Check if both types of products are found
    if ($products_in_category_494 && $products_in_other_categories) {
        $split_order_needed = true;
    }

    // If a split order is needed, proceed to split the order
    if ( $split_order_needed ) {
        // Create new split order
        $split_order = wc_create_order();

        // Iterate through order items
        foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
            // Get the WC_Product Object
            $product = $item->get_product();
            
            // Get categories of the product
            $product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();

            // Check if the product belongs to the specified category (category ID: 494)
            if (in_array('494', $product_categories)) {
                // Add product to the split order
                $split_order->add_product( $product, $item->get_quantity() );

                // Remove product from original order
                $order->remove_item( $item_id );
            }
        }

      
        $split_order->set_address( array(
            'first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
            'last_name'  => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
            'email'      => $order->get_billing_email(),
            'phone'      => $order->get_billing_phone(),
            'address_1'  => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
            'address_2'  => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
            'city'       => $order->get_billing_city(),
            'state'      => $order->get_billing_state(),
            'postcode'   => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
            'country'    => $order->get_billing_country()
        ), 'billing' );

        $split_order->set_address( array(
            'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
            'last_name'  => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
            'address_1'  => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
            'address_2'  => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
            'city'       => $order->get_shipping_city(),
            'state'      => $order->get_shipping_state(),
            'postcode'   => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
            'country'    => $order->get_shipping_country()
        ), 'shipping' );

        // Set the correct currency and payment gateway
        $split_order->set_currency( $order->get_currency() );
        $split_order->set_payment_method( $order->get_payment_method() );

        // Calculate totals
        $split_order->calculate_totals();

        // Set order note with original ID
        $split_order->add_order_note( 'Automated order. Created from the original order ID: ' . $order_id );

      
        $split_order->update_status( 'processing' );

        // Add the split order to the array of split orders
        $split_orders[] = $split_order;
    }

    // Re-calculate & save the original order
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();

    // Store split order data in order meta
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'split_orders', $split_orders );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3 );

//display the split order table on thank you page user dashboard  
function display_split_orders( $order_id ) {
    // Get split orders from order meta
    $split_orders = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'split_orders', true );

    // Check if there are split orders
    if ( ! empty( $split_orders ) ) {
        echo '<section>';
        echo '<h2>Orders 2 Details</h2>';

        // Loop through split orders
        foreach ( $split_orders as $split_order ) {
            echo '<table class="woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--order-details shop_table order_details">';
            
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name" colspan="2">Split Order ID: ' . $split_order->get_id() . '</tr>';
            echo '<th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">Product</th>';
            echo '<th class="woocommerce-table__product-table product-total">Total</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
           
            echo '<tbody>';

            // Loop through items in split order
            foreach ( $split_order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                $product = $item->get_product();
                echo '<tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">';
                echo '<td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name"><a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a><strong class="product-quantity"> × ' . $item->get_quantity() . '</strong></td>';
                echo '<td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price( $item->get_total() ) . '</span></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '<tfoot>';
            echo '<tr><th scope="row">Subtotal:</th><td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price( $split_order->get_subtotal() ) . '</span></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><th scope="row">Total:</th><td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price( $split_order->get_total() ) . '</span></td></tr>';
            echo '</tfoot>';
            echo '</table>';
        }

        echo '</section>';
    } else {
        // echo '<p>No split orders found.</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'display_split_orders' );

function display_split_orders_content_in_table() {
    global $wp;

    // Check if the current URL contains the split orders endpoint
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['split-orders'] ) ) {
        // Get the current user ID
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        // Set pagination parameters
        $orders_per_page = -1;
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $orders_per_page;

        // Get orders for the current user with pagination
        $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'customer'    => $user_id,
            'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' ),
            'limit'       => $orders_per_page,
            'offset'      => $offset,
        ) );

        if ( $customer_orders ) {

            // Display split orders in a table
            echo '<div class="table-responsive splitorder">';
            echo '<table class="table cart-table order-table">';
            echo '<thead><tr><th>Order</th><th>Date</th><th>Status</th><th>Total</th><th>Actions</th></tr></thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';

            foreach ( $customer_orders as $order ) {
                // Get split orders data from order meta
                $split_orders = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'split_orders', true );

                // Check if there are split orders
                if ( ! empty( $split_orders ) ) {
                    foreach ( $split_orders as $split_order ) {
                        // Get split order ID
                        $split_order_id = $split_order->get_id();

                        // Get split order data
                        $split_order_data = $split_order->get_data();

                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-number" ><a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/my-account/split-order/' . $split_order_id ) ) . '">#'. $split_order_id .'</a></td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $order->get_date_created()->date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . wc_get_order_status_name( $split_order->get_status() ) . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . wc_price( $split_order_data['total'] ) .' for '. $split_order->get_item_count() .' items</td>';
                        echo '<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions"><a class="woocommerce-button button view" href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/my-account/split-order/' . $split_order_id ) ) . '">View</a></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                }
            }

            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>';

            // Add pagination
            $total_orders = count( $customer_orders );
            $total_pages = ceil( $total_orders / $orders_per_page );
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'total'   => $total_pages,
                'current' => $paged,
            ) );
        } else {
            // echo '<p>No orders found for the current user.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_split-orders_endpoint', 'display_split_orders_content_in_table' );
// Handle requests to the split-order endpoint order view user 
function display_split_order_content() {
    global $wp;

   
    $current_url = home_url( $wp->request );
    $url_parts = parse_url( $current_url );

    if ( isset( $url_parts['path'] ) && strpos( $url_parts['path'], 'split-order/' ) !== false ) {
        // Extract the order ID from the URL
        $path_parts = explode( '/', $url_parts['path'] );
        $order_id = end( $path_parts );
        $split_order_id = absint( $order_id );

        // Get the split order object
        $split_order = wc_get_order( $split_order_id );

        if ( $split_order && ! is_wp_error( $split_order ) ) {
            // Display split order details
            echo '<p>
          Order #<mark class="order-number">'. $split_order->get_id() .'</mark> was placed on <mark class="order-date">'.$split_order->get_date_created()->date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ) ).'</mark> and is currently <mark class="order-status">'.wc_get_order_status_name( $split_order->get_status() ) .'</mark>.</p>';
            echo '<section>';
            echo '<h2>Order 2 Details:</h2>';
            echo '<table class="woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--order-details shop_table order_details">';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name" colspan="2">Split Order ID: ' . $split_order->get_id() . '</tr>';
            echo '<th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">Product</th>';
            echo '<th class="woocommerce-table__product-table product-total">Total</th>';
            '</tr>';
            '</thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';

            foreach ( $split_order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                echo '<tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">';
                echo '<td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">';
                echo '<a href="' . $item->get_product()->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_name() . '</a>';
                echo '<strong class="product-quantity"> × ' . $item->get_quantity() . '</strong>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">';
                echo '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price( $item->get_total() ) . '</span>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '<tfoot>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="row">Subtotal:</th>';
            echo '<td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price( $split_order->get_subtotal() ) . '</span></td>';
            '</tr>';
            // Add billing address details
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="row">Billing Address:</th>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $split_order->get_formatted_billing_address(); // Display formatted billing address
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

           

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="row">Total:</th>';
echo '<td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price( $split_order->get_total() ) . '</span></td>
echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tfoot>';
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</section>';

        } else {
            // echo '<p>Split order not found.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_split-order_endpoint', 'display_split_order_content' );
```

Comment: You should ask this in a WooCommerce community, questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here